# Topological Sort - Creating a Direct Graph Issue

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, graph, topological-sort

So I'm trying to implement the code, but it's not working properly. I'll put into comments where I'm pretty sure I'm making a mistake. I just started learning this chapter, and it's pretty hard and confusing, but I'm getting into it, that's why I have no idea what's wrong or not, please help.

```
#include "graph.h"
#include "queue.c"
#include "queue.h"
#include "topsort.c"
#include "fatal.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

Graph CreateDirectGraph(void)
{
    int N, i;
    Vertex v, w;
    Graph G;
    PtrToNode p;

    printf("Create Directed Graph:\n");
    printf("Number of vertexs in the graph:\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    G = (struct GraphRecord *)malloc(sizeof(struct GraphRecord));
    G->vertices = (struct VertexRecord *)malloc(sizeof(struct VertexRecord) * (N + 1));
    G->vexnum = N;
    
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        G->vertices[i].adjto = NULL;
    printf("Number of edges in the graph:\n");
    scanf("%d",&N);
    printf("Input %2d edges:\n", N);
    for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
        scanf("%d%d", &v, &w);
        p = ( struct Node *) malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );
        p->adjvex = NextAdjVex(G, v, w);                         /* <-- HERE */
        p->next = G->vertices[v].adjto;                          /* <-- HERE */
        G->vertices[v].adjto = p;                               
    }
    return G;
}

void DestroyGraph(Graph G)
{ /*free space*/
    free(G->vertices);
    free(G);
    return;
}

Vertex FirstAdjVex(Graph G, Vertex v)
{
    if (G->vertices[v].adjto)
        return G->vertices[v].adjto->adjvex;
    else return 0;
}

Vertex NextAdjVex(Graph G, Vertex v, Vertex w)
{
    PtrToNode p;

    p = G->vertices[v].adjto;
    while (p->adjvex != w)
        p = p->next;
    if (p->next) return p->next->adjvex;
    return 0;
}

int NumOfVex(Graph G)
{
    return G->vexnum;
}

int Topsort( Graph G, int TopNum[] )
{   
    Queue Q;
    int V, W, N;
    int  Counter = 0;
    int *Indegree;
    PtrToNode p;

    N = NumOfVex(G);
    Indegree = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*(N + 1));
    for (V=1; V<=N; V++)
        Indegree[V] = 0;
    for (V=1; V<=N; V++)
        for (p =G->vertices[V].adjto; p; p = p->next)
            Indegree[p->adjvex]++;
    Q = CreateQueue( N );  
    for (V = 1; V <= N; V++)
        if ( Indegree[ V ] == 0 )   Enqueue( V, Q );
    while ( !IsEmpty( Q ) ) {
        V = Dequeue( Q );
        TopNum[ ++ Counter ] = V; /* assign next */                   /* <-- HERE */
        for (W = FirstAdjVex(G, V); W; W = NextAdjVex(G, V, W))
            if ( --Indegree[W] == 0 )  Enqueue( W, Q );              /* <-- HERE */
    }  /* end-while */
    DisposeQueue( Q ); /* free memory */
    if ( Counter != N )
        return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

`/* <-- HERE */` means I probably made a mistake there, because I'm 99% sure the rest is correct, as I was being partly guided

OUTPUT:

```
Number of vertexs in the graph:
4
Number of edges in the graph:
4
Input  4 edges:
1 2
```

Then the runtime stops

Comment: `for (i = 1; i <= N; i++)
        G->vertices[i].adjto = NULL;` <<-- Indexing starts at zero in C.

Comment: @wildplasser I'm not sure I understand :/

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <  N; i++)
        G->vertices[i].adjto = NULL;`

Comment: @wildplasser isn't that exactly the same? I just increased it by one and made it smaller or equal to N

Comment: Yes, it is the same in that case. I didnot see it because I refuse to scroll tot the right. [Hint: remove the cast]

Comment: @wildplasser ok thank you, but it still won't work :/

Comment: In `NextAdjVex`, you access `p->advvex` without checking whether `p` is null, which it is at the beginning. I'm not sute why you call `NextAdjVex` when you create the graph, probably to avoid duplicates in the adjacency list. But `NextAdjVex` returns the vertex id after `w`. I think it should just be `p->adjvex = w`.

Comment: @MOehm THANK YOU! You were absolutely correct. That was the only issue.

Comment: So, it was a style issue, after all.